# Coin Simulator - Python 3 - Using Lists & Count()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just playing around with lists and have stumbled across an issue with my code. I can't figure out why my count() won't actually work and display the final total for the heads and tails. It prints 0 rather than what's in the new list..? I've tested the print newlist and it is showing that the list is updating once the loop has completed.

Can anyone help me fix this and explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
import random

i = 0

spins = int(input ("How many spins do you want to do? "))
coin = ["heads", "tails"]
newList = []

while i < spins:
    i = i+1
    spin = random.sample(set(coin),1)
    tallyCoin = spin
    print (tallyCoin)
    newList.append(tallyCoin)

if i >= spins:
    print (newList)
    totalHeads = newList.count("heads")
    totalTails = newList.count("tails")
    print ("the total heads for this round were: ", totalHeads)
    print ("the total tails for this round were: ", totalTails)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.sample` returns a list so you are collecting lists with a single string in it instead of strings. Try `random.sample(coin, 1)[0]` instead.